# Angularjs using "this" keyword inside promise call back

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently my controller looks like the following. I have to create a new variable `parent` to store controller's context so that i can use it inside the promise returned by the login function. The login function is inside another service.

Is there a to use `this` keyword to reference the response object instead of a using a variable and storing current context inside it? The login function is called from ng-click event.

```
function loginCtrl(Service, $state) {
    this.emailAddress =null; 
    this.password = null;
    var parent = this;
    parent.response = common.getNewResponseObject();

    this.login = function () {
        Service.login(this.emailAddress, this.password)
        .success(success)
        .error(error);
    }

    function error(data) {
        parent.response.errorResponse = { errors: [{ message: data.error_description }] }
    }

    function success(data) {
        authService.setAuthData(data);
        $state.go(common.states.dashboard);
    }
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('loginCtrl', ['Service', '$state', loginCtrl])
```

Comment: Attach vm to this using Var vm=this

Comment: that doesn't make any difference. i want to be able to do this.response inside the promise callback.

Comment: Assign variable right at beginning and don't use `this` again for consistency. See [John Papa angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y032)

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking

Comment: @joe attach it to VM right at the beginnng and you can use vm.whatever but vm is always attached to this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can 'inject' the enclosing block's value of `this` in a function using the bind method, and passing in the value of this.

eg.

```
var error = (function (data) {
    this.response.errorResponse = { errors: [{ message: data.error_description }] }
}).bind(this);
```

However I'm not sure why you don't just set it as this.error, so you don't have to call bind.